# Adding Done button to number pad within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using dynamic cells within a UITableview and am trying to **create a done button that will display with the numberpad within a UITableViewCell**.

I have the code to accomplish this within a ViewController for other fields, but this does not work when the field in within a UITableViewCell.

IBOulet is here:

```
class StartingTankUsageCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var startingPressureTextField: UITextField!
```

I have set up in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DiveDetailsViewController: UITableViewController, LocationDelegate, ItemDataSelectedProtocol
{

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboardStartingPressure()
}

// DONE button on NumberPad for StartingPressure
func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardStartingPressure()
{
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(DiveDetailsViewController.addDoneButtonOnKeyboardStartingPressure))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.startingPressureTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}

func doneButtonActionDuration()
{
    self.startingPressureTextField.resignFirstResponder()
} // finish DONE button on NumberPad for StartingPressure
```

The error I am getting is `"Value to type 'DiveDetailsViewController' has no member 'startingPressureTextField'"`

Can someone please help me either the allow the vc to see the UITextField in the UITableViewCell or help me with a done button that can reside within the UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make an extension for UITextField like this:

```
extension UITextField {

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addHideinputAccessoryView()
    }

    func addHideinputAccessoryView() {

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 50,height: 44))
        button.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.resignFirstResponder), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44))

        toolbar.items = [space, barButton]
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this to the StartingTankUsageCell, but i am getting the error "declaration only valid at file scope"  I have tried various changes, but no go

Comment: How did you add this in your cell ? Try to add this extension outside cell

Comment: exactly, i did.  However, then I had many unresolved identifiers.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the original post

Comment: I am pretty sure that you missed something. Check your code, maybe you missed to close some brace somewhere in your cell.

Comment: I use custom colors and fonts, use default and should work.
like UIColor.blackColor() or  UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)

Comment: Radu, I just realized you updated the code you posted.  This now works Perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: Radu, I  have 3 classes I need to add this too.  I now see that this is not possible.  What do I need to rename to allow this in multiple classes in my app?

Comment: Here we made an extension for UITextField if you will use in other parts of your app also textfields this should work. But if you will want to make this also for other controls you need extension also for that control( e.g UITextVIew)

Answer (score 3):

You could also try it this way, simplify the code a little bit:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UITextField {

    func addHideinputAccessoryView() {

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done,
                                   target: self, action: #selector(self.resignFirstResponder))
        toolbar.setItems([item], animated: true)

        self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirri.  There is no "Done" button or any object to press to remove the number pad

Comment: Interesting. Works in my simulator (ios 9.3).